# SQL Error 1062: Primary key problems

Tags: mysql, sql

**My code:**

```
insert into userEmail ( userEmailId, userId, userEmail, userEmailTypeId )
values ('1005', 'a1a2', 'Dberkeley@fullsail.edu', '1');
```

I get....

> 19:06:22  insert into userEmail ( userEmailId, userId, userEmail,
>   userEmailTypeId ) values ('1005', 'a1a2', 'Dberkeley@fullsail.edu',
>   '1')  Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '1005' for key
>   'PRIMARY' 0.00033 sec

Comment: Assuming the `useremailid` is an auto increment, just leave it out of the insert statement and let the database handle it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that you have a record with 1005 as the userEmailId.

```
SELECT * 
FROM userEmail 
WHERE userEmailId=1005
```

If the above query returns a row there's your proof.

Answer (score 0):

Run this query:

```
Select * from UserEmail
```

You will see that UserEmailID (1005) already exist. Try to insert 1006 or 1007 or 1008 etc etc..